# How to select from the database within a option that is filled with JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm new to razor page

I have an edit page - that it has 2 selection tags

- 1 - "MissionTime" and the other - "MissionDay".
  The choices in MissionDay vary according to the choice of MissionTime.
  In terms of JavaScript it works great! On the Create page it works really well.

Also on the edit page **it works well on the part of the JavaScript.**
The problem is when the database has information () **but it does not select according to the value in the database.**

```
        <div class = "col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for = "Mission.MissionTime" class = "control-label"> </label>

             <select id = "MissionTime" asp-for = "Mission.MissionTime">
                <option value = "0">
                    with no
                </option>
                <option value = "1">
                    Every day
                </option>
                <option value = "7">
                    once a week
                </option>
                <option value = "30">
                    once a month
                </option>
                <option value = "365">
                    Once a year
                </option>
            </select>
        </div> <div class = "col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for = "Mission.MissionDay" class = "control-label"> </label>
            <select id = "MissionDay" asp-for = "Mission.MissionDay">
                <option value = "0">
                    with no
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Code JavaScript -

```
  <script>

    $ (document) .ready (function () {

        missionTime ();


        $ ("#MissionTime"). Change (function () {
            missionTime ();
        });

        $ ("#MissionDay"). Change (function () {
            var d = new Date ();
            var val = $ (this) .val ();
            if (val == "Sunday") {

                d.setDate (d.getDate () + ((7 - d.getDay ())% 7 + 0)% 7);

            } else if (val == "Monday") {
                d.setDate (d.getDate () + ((7 - d.getDay ())% 7 + 1)% 7);
            } else if (val == "Tuesday") {
                d.setDate (d.getDate () + ((7 - d.getDay ())% 7 + 2)% 7);
            } else if (val == "Wednesday") {
                d.setDate (d.getDate () + ((7 - d.getDay ())% 7 + 3)% 7);
            } else if (val == "Thursday") {
                d.setDate (d.getDate () + ((7 - d.getDay ())% 7 + 4)% 7);
            }
            else if (val == "startMonth") {

                d.setMonth (d.getMonth () + 1, 1);
            }
            else if (val == "middleMonth") {
                // if 15th of current month is over move to next month
                // need to check whether to use> = or just> ie on 15th Jun
                // if you want 15 Jun then use> else if you want 15 Jul use> =
                var dt = d.getDate ();
                d.setDate (15);
                if (dt> = 15) {
                    d.setMonth (date.getMonth () + 1);
                }
                d.setHours (23, 59, 59, 0);
            }
            else if (val == "endMonth") {

                d.setMonth (d.getMonth () + 1);
                d.setDate (0);
            }
            else if (val == "firstYear") {

                d = new Date (new Date (). getFullYear () +1, 0, 1);

            }
            else if (val == "lastYear") {

                d = new Date (new Date (). getFullYear (), 11, 31);
            }

            var dd = String (d.getDate ()). padStart (2, '0');
            var mm = String (d.getMonth () + 1) .padStart (2, '0'); // January is 0!
            var yyyy = d.getFullYear ();

            d = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

            document.getElementById ("firstDate"). value = d;
        }
        );






        function missionTime () {
            var val = $ ("# MissionTime"). val ();
            if (val == "1") {
                $ ("#MissionDay"). Html ("<option value = '0'> without </option>");
                today ();
            } else if (val == "7") {
                $ ("#MissionDay"). Html ("<option value = 'Sunday'> Sunday </option> <option value = 'Monday'> Monday </option> <option value = 'Tuesday'> Tuesday < / option> <option value = 'Wednesday'> Wednesday </option> <option value = 'Thursday'> Thursday </option> ");

                var d = new Date ();
                d.setDate (d.getDate () + ((7 - d.getDay ())% 7 + 0)% 7);
                var dd = String (d.getDate ()). padStart (2, '0');
                var mm = String (d.getMonth () + 1) .padStart (2, '0'); // January is 0!
                var yyyy = d.getFullYear ();

                d = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

                document.getElementById ("firstDate"). value = d;

            } else if (val == "30") {
                . / option> ");
                var d = new Date ();
                d.setMonth (d.getMonth () + 1, 1);
                var dd = String (d.getDate ()). padStart (2, '0');
                var mm = String (d.getMonth () + 1) .padStart (2, '0'); // January is 0!
                var yyyy = d.getFullYear ();
                d = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
                document.getElementById ("firstDate"). value = d;

            } else if (val == "365") {
                $ ("#MissionDay"). Html ("<option value = 'firstYear'> beginning of year </option> <option value = 'lastYear'> end of year </option>");

            } else if (val == "0") {
                $ ("#MissionDay"). Html ("<option value = '0'> without </option>");
                today ();

            }
        }




        function today () {

            var today = new Date ();
            var dd = String (today.getDate ()). padStart (2, '0');
            var mm = String (today.getMonth () + 1) .padStart (2, '0'); // January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear ();

            today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

            document.getElementById ("firstDate"). value = today;
        }






    });
</script>
```

The code works great!
The problem is that I can not get the data in the "MissionDay"

I  guess this is because first the page takes data from the database and only then does it run the script. Anyone have any tips on how to solve this problem?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is when the database has information () but it does not select according to the value in the database.

Please note that the option(s) that you generate on JavaScript client could not be available when the [Select Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-select-tag-helper) is rendered. Therefore it does not set default selected option based on the data passed through `Mission.MissionDay`.

To achieve your requirement of setting the default selected option based on the stored `MissionDay`, you can try to store the data in a hidden field, then set the selected option in JavaScript code, like below.

*Add a hidden field with `id="hf_missionDay"`*

```
<label asp-for="Mission.MissionDay" class="control-label"> </label>
<input type="hidden" id="hf_missionDay" value="Mission.MissionDay" />
<select id="MissionDay" asp-for="Mission.MissionDay">
    <option value="0">
        with no
    </option>
</select>
```

*Set selected option based on the data store in hidden field*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    missionTime();

    SetSelectionOfMissionDay();

    //...
    //your code logic here
    //...
```

*SetSelectionOfMissionDay function*

```
function SetSelectionOfMissionDay() {
    var mday = $("#hf_missionDay").val();

    $("select#MissionDay option[value='" + mday + "']").attr("selected", true);
    //or
    //$("select#MissionDay").val(mday);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for both the explanation and the wonderful solution. I just had to change the 
<input value="Mission.MissionDay" /> to  asp-for="Mission.MissionDay"